# What scripts is running that loads the page?

Tags: javascript, python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrap data from the following table:

https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/

I put in dates from 2010-2017, but the chart only loads bit by bit. How can I get around this. In the HTML code I can see the table grow when I scroll down but I can't pinpoint the script that is responsible for this. I want to load the entire table then scrap it with bs4. I don't want to automate the scrolling, that will take forever.

Comment: I'd use breakpoints to stop execution and look at the callstack that triggers that. Provide a working example (codepen.io or jsfiddle) and you might receive the actual answer.

Comment: How do i provide a sample?

Comment: go to https://codepen.io/pen/ add some stuff and give the link after youve saved it :)

Comment: When I say html code, im talking about elements i can inspect on chrome. Not actually code I've written.

Comment: I mean that I would try to put a breakpoint/pauze script (web inspector), then scroll to trigger js, and see where the execution continues